# How to determine a coplaner perpendicular vector?

Tags: vectors

How do I determine a perpendicular vector of a given vector on a given plane ? I can't think of any way put the theories of dot product in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Take the cross product of the given vector and the normal vector of the plane. The resulting vector is perpendicular to both vectors, so it is perpendicular to the given vector and lies on the plane as required.

Answer (score 1):

Your vector satisfies two conditions: it is perpendicular to the normal vector of the given plane (since it is parallel to the given plane) and it is perpendicular to the given vector. Just cross-multiply those vectors to get your answer.